# How to connect mtp android device to ubuntu 13.10

Tags: usb, android, mtp

I searched here and google and all I could find is how in Ubuntu 13.04 forward mtp devices are supported. The answer I found are for ubuntu 12.04 or ubuntu 12.10

Well, I connected my phone in mtp mode and I don't see it on my machine. How can I see it?

Edit: Requested data

[This](http://xtreamermobile.com/q/) is my phone (Xtreamer q)

I also tried a samsung galaxy s2 device, which popped an error message (unable to mount device). My phone didn't give such mistake.

And this is the output of lsusb and mtp-detect

```
└┌(%:~/Applications/Process.1dFit)┌- lsusb
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 04f2:b1fc Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 045e:009d Microsoft Corp. Wireless Optical Desktop 3.0
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 283b:10a3  
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0424:2514 Standard Microsystems Corp. USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:217f Broadcom Corp. BCM2045B (BDC-2.1)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
┌┌(y2@walking)┌(15/pts/0)┌(03:52pm:11/14/13)┌-
└┌(%:~/Applications/Process.1dFit)┌- mtp-detect 
Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.libmtp version: 1.1.6

Listing raw device(s)
   No raw devices found.
```

I guess that the third text line from the bottom is the problem. But I don't what to do with it.

Comment: Then that's not a problem with mtp support or Ubuntu but your device. Which you haven't told us.

Comment: Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/376815/edit) your question and add the output of the following commands: `lsusb` and `mtp-detect`. Your android must to be connected when you run these commands.

Comment: I actually have the same problem on Kubuntu 13.10 with my HTC One X+. Ill be keeping an eye on this post for any answers and will post my own if I find anything.

Comment: @Yotam It was your phone connected to your system when you ran `lsusb` and `mtp-detect`? If it was, as I can see, your phone is not detected. Try to connect it to another machine to see if the problem persists.

Comment: @Dadu Daideanu. On another machine I don't have that problem. I also tried two other USB ports with the same result.

Comment: @Yotam: can you check if mtp is enabled on the phone? To do this you should go to Settings->Storage->option buttons (the upper right icon with 3 points). With mtp enabled (the first combo checked), mtp-tools and mtpfs packages installed should work. Hope it helps. Dario.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I too had the problem that my "asus padfone infinity" was not mounted through mtp. (adb worked though).

Solution was to connect it through one of the USB3 Ports of my thinkpad instead of a usb2 port. Looks like the USB2 port is not recognized as usb2, or are devicenames for usb2 "usb1"?

**syslog when connecting to USB2 Port**:

```
Feb 21 13:59:55 t530 kernel: [39597.968522] usb-storage 1-1.2:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
Feb 21 13:59:55 t530 kernel: [39597.968634] scsi16 : usb-storage 1-1.2:1.2
Feb 21 13:59:55 t530 mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 7: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2"
Feb 21 13:59:55 t530 mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 7 was not an MTP device
Feb 21 13:59:56 t530 kernel: [39598.966743] scsi 16:0:0:0: CD-ROM            ASUS     Device CD-ROM    0000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Feb 21 13:59:56 t530 kernel: [39598.971140] sr1: scsi-1 drive
Feb 21 13:59:56 t530 kernel: [39598.971427] sr 16:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
Feb 21 13:59:56 t530 kernel: [39598.971580] sr 16:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5
Feb 21 14:01:02 t530 kernel: [39665.530135] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 7
```

**Connecting to usb 3.0 port**:

```
Feb 21 14:01:06 t530 kernel: [39669.292066] usb-storage 3-1:1.2: USB Mass Storage device detected
Feb 21 14:01:06 t530 kernel: [39669.292231] scsi17 : usb-storage 3-1:1.2
Feb 21 14:01:06 t530 mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1"
Feb 21 14:01:06 t530 mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 2 was an MTP device
```

Comment: Apparently, this is the case with my machine as well. My (new) nexus 7 device is mounted through some usb ports, but not all. My phone isn't recognize at any though.

Comment: This isn't the problem. I also get "device: 2 was an MTP device" but I'm still not able to mount my phone.

Answer (score 28):

I had the same issue, and the following worked

```
sudo apt-get install mtp-tools mtpfs
```

Comment: Worked for me on Kubuntu 13.10. Thanks!

Comment: Just worked for me too. My Nexus 4 was mouting, but won't let me open any folder, after those installs, everything is working. Thanks.

Comment: Didn't work for me on Ubuntu 14.04 and with HTC Desire 500 on USB2 port.

Comment: Didn't work for me in Lubuntu 14.04

Comment: I run the above + changed the settings on my device (in this case, a sansa clip plus by sandisk) to use MTP (System settings->USB->MTP) and it worked!

Comment: I didn't need (on 14.04) neither mtp-tools nor mtpfs. What I needed was to log in to my phone! (Samsung GT-i8150 aka Galaxy W)

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.debugpoint.com/2016/03/how-to-access-android-devices-internal-storage-and-sd-card-in-ubuntu-linux-mint-using-media-transfer-protocol-mtp/) worked for me, under 16.04 LTS.
I am essentially copying it, just in case the link dies.

1. Install libmtp, FUSE file system for MTP enabled devices mtpfs using below commands

   ```
   sudo apt-get install go-mtpfs
   sudo apt-get install libmtp
   sudo apt-get install mtpfs mtp-tools
   ```

---

*CROSSED*

2. Create a directory in /media using below command and change the permission for write

   ```
   sudo mkdir /media/MTPdevice
   sudo chmod 775 /media/MTPdevice
   sudo mtpfs -o allow_other /media/MTPdevice
   ```

---

3. Plug in your Android device using USB cable in Ubuntu.
   In your Android device, swipe down from above in the home screen and click Touch for more options. In the next menu, select option “Transfer File (MTP)“.
4. Run below command in terminal to find out the device ID etc. You can see the VID and PID in the command output for your device. Note down these two numbers.

   ```
   $ mtp-detect
   ```
5. Open the android rules file using text editor using below command.

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules
   ```
6. Type below line using your device’s VID and PID in the 51-android.rules file. Save and close the file.

   ```
   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="22b8", ATTR{idProduct}=="2e82", MODE="0666"
   ```
7. Run below command to restart the device manager.

   ```
   sudo service udev restart
   ```
8. Next steps are mainly needed to access the contents of external SD card memory of your android device. I had to do these because the file manager was NOT showing the contents of the SD card. This is not a solution though but it is a work-around which works for most of the users as per this Google forum post and worked for my Motorola G 2nd Gen with SanDisk SD card.

   - Safely remove your connected device in Ubuntu.
   - Turn off the device. Remove the SD card from the device.
   - Turn on the device without the SD card.
   - Turn off the device again.
   - Put the SD card back in and turn on the device again.
9. Reboot your Ubuntu machine and plug-in your android device.
10. Now you can see the contents of your android device internal storage and the SD card contents.

Answer (score 0):

Android fs can be explored if you MTP(media transfer protocol) file system on your system. Install the MTP file system on your system. Then try to plug your mobile. I tried on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and android Samsung Galaxy S3. I hope, yours will be worked.

installation of MTP file system on ubuntu.

```
sudo apt-get install mtpfs
```

Now, unplug and plug your mobile. Then, restart your computer if still not working.

Comment: E: Unable to locate package mtpfs

Comment: please, have look on this link. 

https://installati.one/install-go-mtpfs-ubuntu-20-04/