# MTP connection in Ubuntu 13.10 without no USB 3.0

Tags: 13.10, usb, android, mtp

In this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/376815/how-to-connect-mtp-android-device-to-ubuntu-13-10) I read that Ubuntu 13.10 does recognize my phone, but only if it has a USB 3.0 port. Is that correct? My computer has only 3 USB ports and all are 2.0. It is a Dell Vostro 3500. When I run the command:

```
$ mtp-detect
```

I get the following answer:

> *Unable to open ~/.mtpz-data for reading, MTPZ disabled.libmtp version: 1.1.6*
>
> *Listing raw device(s)*
>
> *No raw devices found.*

I installed everything (from *mtp* to *gmtp*), and tried all the solutions I found in web, but nothing until now.

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Please tell us the complete name of the device and post the output of `lsusb -v`.

Comment: Voting to close as there is still information missing about the device, so the question cannot be completely answered (getting the device in question to work).

Answer (score 1):

**No**, that is a misleading answer.

Most, if not all, MTP enabled devices currently feature a USB 2.0 port. They can technically not switch to USB 3.0 mode and are always served by the operating system of your host computer as USB 2.0 devices (or worse, depending on the USB controller of the host computer, the cable used or other glitches).

When the software (libmtp) cannot find your device, the first step would be to find out if your device is supported by the software. While the libmtp project does not maintain a list of supported devices, searching online for "libmtp supported device" + device name + USB vendor ID and device ID should give you results. If in doubt, just follow the procedures on the [project homepage](http://libmtp.sourceforge.net/) to open a support request for adding a **new device**.

Answer (score 0):

Use filezilla on Ubuntu with android app ftp server to transfer wathever jou want via wifi, ten use app sdrescan to update your music player. Search YouTube there s video from oheyitslou wit titel 'transfer files from any Linux desktop to any android device'
Works like a charm. No mtp needed!! All credits to oheyitslou on YouTube

Comment: This doesn't answer how to get MTP working and I'm sure such a workaround has been proposed before in similar questions.