# How do you connect a Tesco hudl 2 to Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04, android

Sirs,

I have Ubuntu 15.04 and have been given a hudl 2 tablet.  Is it possible to easily connect and transfer files between these two (say, via the USB cable) ?

Having tried MTP and gMTP, I find the USB settings on the hudl are impossible to change or even access.  I think that this problem must lie doggo, for a while.

Comment: As it probably uses bog standard Android, it should work out the box, or if you [install MTP](http://askubuntu.com/a/377668/178596) on the Ubuntu machine.